# How do I remove Work Offline from Outlook 2007

Tags: outlook-2007

Outlook 2003, 2007 and 2010 have the option to "Work Offline".

People mistakenly click on Work Offline, instead of Print, from the File menu in Outlook.  We need to disable Work Offline, or remove it, or move it from this menu.

This is using Outlook in a non-Exchange environment.

Answer (score 3):

In Outlook 2003 you'll need to use the Outlook 2003 ADM template in your GPO to define a custom item to disable in the user interface, you need to reference the Command Bar ID for the particular menu item that you want to disable.

In Outlook 2007 and 2010 you'll need use the Outlook 2007 and 2010 ADM or ADMX template to define a custom item to disable in the user interface, you need to reference the Ribbon Control ID for the particular menu item that you want to disable.